# Why does the INDIRECT function in Excel not work for strings representing non-contiguous cells?

Tags: excel, sum, range

I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

```
   A     B            C              D
```

.1
.2...............7.............................................52...... <== SUM(B2:B11)
.3...............2..............................................................
.4...............3..............................................................
.5...............1..............B2:B11...................52...... <== SUM(INDIRECT(C5))
.6...............9..............................................................
.7...............2..............................................................
.8...............3.............................................38...... <==  SUM(B2:B2,B4:B6,B9:B10)
.9..............10..............................................................
.10.............8..............................................................
.11..............7....B2:B2,B4:B6,B9:B10....#REF!... <== SUM(INDIRECT(C11))
.12

Cells B2:B11 contain certain values, and I want to do a SUM of either all values, or only values from selected cells. A simple SUM function works for that (entered in cells D2 and D8).

However, if I want to use INDIRECT to reference a string that represents the cells, it works only for one continuous range (cell D5) and not for non-contiguous ranges (cell D11).

I would like to know why.

Comment: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/23680-indirect-with-multiple-range-or-selection/

Comment: ...as to why it doesn't work - that was presumably a design decision.

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams. That workaround using SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIF looks neat. But, I guess, that means we would need to look for different workarounds for other functions such as RANK etc. Right?

Comment: Yes but you could consider other approaches such as defining names for the range you want and the use `SUM(your_range_name)`.  Difficult to suggest without knowing why you need to use this approach.

Comment: The range is determined based on a condition (say, values in another column like A2:A11). I am able to build a string that represents the needed range. I was just looking at ways to use the string with any function that takes a range as a parameter. Purely theoretical interest, I don't have a specific problem to solve.